# Entity Framework nesting classes inside class

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-mvc-5, model, entity-framework-6

I trying to make a data model that allows users to add companies to a list and then when added, allow further details on the company to be added, this is to allow things like employee information to be added. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this without creating multiple class, controller files and view folders.

My current code on the model class file is:

```
namespace Intranet.Models
{
    public class AddCustomers
    {
        public int AddCustomersID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        ...

        public class EmployeeInfo
        {
            public int EmployeeInfoID { get; set; }
            public string Forename { get; set; }
            ...
        }

        public class ContactInfo
        {
            public int ContactInfoID { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Context file:

```
public IntranetContext() : base("name=IntranetContext")
{
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.AddCustomers> AddCustomers { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.AddCustomers.EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.AddCustomers.ContactInfo> ContactInfo { get; set; }
```

This does not work however as the nested classes do not appear anywhere, except in my local database.

Is there a way I can get the nested classes to appear in the details view for each customer? Or is there a completely different way to do this?

Comment: Why do you nest. Add navigational properties to your entity class.

Comment: @Shyju I am still new to Entity Framework, would you mind linking an example/guide please.

Comment: With the example code given nothing is using those classes  (`EmployeeInfo` and `ContactInfo`).  So while they're defined, and you've declared that you have them in the DB within the context, there's nothing to say that a *instance* of `AddCustomers` contains any direct link to an *instance* of either `EmployeeInfo` or `ContactInfo`.

Comment: @GPW do you know what I would need to do/add to link `EmployeeInfo` and `ContactInfo` to the `AddCustomers` details view only?

Comment: @Riley - see my answer...  you need *properties* on the `AddCustomer` class which are of the appropriate type.  Generally nesting classes isn't necessary;  your code would end up cleaner by separating classes - after all these would be separate tables in the database with foreign keys defining their relationship.  The same is broadly true of the entities.  There are some situations where nesting a class is sensible...  This is almost certainly not one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace Intranet.Models
{
    public class AddCustomers
    {
        public int AddCustomersID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public EmployeeInfo EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        public int EmployeeInfoID { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class ContactInfo
    {
        public int ContactInfoID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        ...
    }        
}
```

Then in your context you would have:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.AddCustomers> AddCustomers { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Intranet.Models.ContactInfo> ContactInfo { get; set; }
```

..and in controller you could do things like:

```
var customer = context.AddCustomers
    .FirstOrDefault(c=>c.EmployeeInfo.Forename=="bob");
...
```